# PSTricks error, but package not loaded

Tags: errors, pstricks, mactex

I am working on a textbook, with a looming deadline, so I admit I did not do an exhaustive search for a solution to this situation.  I was hoping someone would see this and say, "This is a duplicate of..." and direct me there.

I just upgraded to MacTex 2011, and when I compile the textbook documents, the console always pops up with...

"LaTex Error: You have run the document with pdflatex, but PSTricks requires..."

Ok...we don't load the PSTricks package at all, and before the upgrade this error wasn't showing up at all.

I should say that if I simply hit "Return" the compiler happily forges ahead and compiles the documents just fine.

Anyone know what the deal is?  Thanks!

Update:  Sorry for the delay.  Work has been a little crazy.  I tracked down the culprit, but I don't know why the error is occuring in the MacTex 2011.  Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{boites,boites_exemples}
\begin{document}
Filler Text Goes Here
\end{document}
```

To be honest, I didn't add this package in, my co-author did, so he must need the functionality.  The full list of packages hasn't changed much over the past year, so it isn't that this was added and then the break-down occurred.

Comment: run the document with `xelatex` or have alook at http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pdf/pdfoutput

Comment: A [minimal working example](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl) would help here. We don't know what documentclass, other packages, or anything else about your document at the moment.

Comment: I'll see if I can upload an MWE later tonight.  It's using the report documentclass.  I was hoping I'd stumbled on to a known issue with MacTex 2011 and PSTricks.

Comment: @Herbert the url you gave me seems to be focused on helping people who want pdf while they use PSTricks.  I'm not using it.  My co-author (who has not upgraded to MacTex 2011) is not getting this error.

Comment: @Herbert xelatex did work.  How odd...

Comment: Note that at least one of your included packages might rely on [PSTricks](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks), thus loads related packages subsequently. A [minimal example](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl) as already requested by @MikeRenfro would really be very helpful.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig I agree.  What is odd is that it compiled just fine before the upgrade to MacTex 2011.  The .tex files did not change.  It still compiles on my co-authors computer (another mac, running an older version of MacTex).  I'm working on a minimal example, and will post when I can.

Comment: @HTG: That's strange. Seems as if it will not be easy to find out the culprit. You could add the `\listfiles` command as very first line to your code, compile on the machine where it works and so find out the package versions. Afterwards compare with the versions on your machine either by compiling in nonstop mode or looking at the package manuals.

Comment: @HTG: In agreeance with @ ThorstenDonig, it could be that some dependencies were deprecated or introduced with a merge to MacTeX 2011, causing the problem.

Comment: Added an MWE to the original post.  Thanks for looking over it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Line 82 of `boites_examples.sty` is:

```
 \RequirePackage{pstricks}
```

So your document definitely *does* load PSTricks and therfore requires compilation with `latex+dvips` or with XeLaTeX as Herbert suggests.

As to the reason for the apparent difference in MacTeX versions, there are a couple of possibilities. This is pure speculation on my part:

- The earlier version of the source had the line `% !TEX TS-program = latex` in it, and TeXShop was automatically using `latex+dvips`
- TeXShop preferences used to be set to `latex+dvips` instead of `pdflatex`

(Assuming you are using TeXShop to edit).

Comment: I've tried all the proposed fixes I can find, but none seem to work.  At least I know why the error is happening now.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "proposed fixes".  To avoid the error (if you are using TeXShop or TeXworks) add the comment line in the first bullet point of my answer to your source, and the file will compile correctly.

Comment: Add it where?  I've tried adding it to 1) the headers file (both before and after the `\documentclass` line), 2) the main source file (both before and after the `\begin{document}`, and 3) the source code for the chapter.  There was still there every time.

Comment: @HTG The comment line needs to be at the very beginning of your source file (before the `\documentclass` line if that's your first line; earlier if you have a lot of commented lines at the top).  If you are using multiple files with `\include` you only need it in the main source file. If you are using TeXShop, go to Macros -> Program and select `latex` from the list of engines and TeXShop will insert the line in the correct place for you.

Comment: Now this is interesting.  When I tried your suggestion on the MWE I posted it worked.  When I tried the same thing with the full text, it didn't.  I trashed the aux files and ran it again (twice) but that didn't help.

Comment: More information that might help: The main source file calls uses `\include{headers}` then `\begin{document}` followed by a long list of `\Chapter{number}{file}` which is a user-defined command which sets the counters and then uses `\input{file}` to bring in the chapter contents.

Comment: I realized I hadn't directed my last two comments at you directly, so I thought you might not have seen them.  I'm hoping for a little more help, if you can.

Comment: @HTG This sounds like a job for a live chat. I've created a chat room for us to talk in.

Answer (score 0):

In Latexian, this problem is solved by setting the file type for `.tex` files  to either "LaTeX (DVI)" or "XeTeX".